# How to get exit code after running command in cmd in windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, createprocess

I am using `Createprocess` to run command in cmd and I am trying to get exit code of that specific command execution using `GetExitCodeProcess()`.

If command window is open and I try `GetExitCodeProcess()` then I get `259(STILL_ACTIVE)` return code always. If I try to terminate the process using `TerminateProcess()` then I get exit code the value I sent to terminate the process.

Below is my code:

```
    STARTUPINFO si;   
    ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    BOOL b =  CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe","/k dir",NULL,NULL,TRUE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);

    TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess,1);

    DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
    ::GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode);
```

I should get nonzero error code when I pass `/k dir` as command and zero error code if I pass`/k dirancbdf`(any nonexistent command).

Another reason to use `Terminateprocess` is I want to hide/Show Command prompt based on success/failure of that command.

Comment: You do know that [`TerminateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx) will attempt to actually terminate the process, even if it's not finished yet? Also, it is *asynchronous*! Please read the linked reference for more information.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're trying to achieve here, but you should probably be using `/c` rather than `/k` and leaving out the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag.  You might also need to create a console first if you don't already have one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, i know that. If i don't use TerminateProcess and try to get exit code, i will get 259(STILL_ACTIVE) always. what is the alternative for that?

Comment: This is a really poor way to get a directory listing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have shown here just simple example of command. i want to run different command in real.

Comment: Maybe you need `WaitForSingleObject`. Put `WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);` after `CreateProcess`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I have used WaitForSingleObject also but no luck.

Comment: If the actual command you want to run is an external command - an application - then you can run it directly rather than via `cmd.exe`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I just want to get correct exit code of command from console after using CreateProcess as simple as it is.

Comment: You aren't going to achieve that though are you because cmd.exe won't give it to you. If you would tell us why you want to do the impossible then we can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing option `/k` to `cmd.exe`, meaning you want the shell to remain active after executing command `dir`. Doing this way, the process running the command will never ends and you will always get `STILL_ACTIVE` when querying `GetExitCodeProcess()` (meaning the process is still running).

If you want the exit code of the `dir` command, you should use option `/c` instead (so that `cmd.exe` ends after executig command `dir`). Moreother, you should wait for the process to end using `WaitForSingleObject()` before querying `GetExitCodeProcess()`, because `CreateProcess()` will return immediately after creation of the process (it does not wait for the process to end). No need to call `TerminateProcess()` in this case : the `dir` command return status wil be available from `GetExitCodeProcess()`.

```
BOOL b =  CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe","/c dir",NULL,NULL,TRUE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );  // wait for process to end
DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
::GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode);
```

If you want the console to remain open if an error occur, you can use the following syntax :

```
CreateProcessA("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe","/c dir || pause && exit 1",NULL,NULL,TRUE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);
```

where `||` ensures that the `pause` command is executed only if `dir` command fails, and `&&` ensures that a an exit code of 1 is ouput in case of such an error.

Comment: I have used /c instead of /k but i am getting 0 exit code for "/c dir" and 1 exit code for "/c dirabc" (any wrong command). i think i should get nonzero value for success as per document of GetExitCodeProcess.

Comment: No, the convention is that an exit code of zero indicates success and a nonzero exit code indicates failure - although this is only a convention, not a rule, and is subject to the whim of the programmer.  (For `robocopy`, for example, any exit code less than 4 indicates success.)

Comment: @shrike Thanks. I have used WaitForSingleObject also but i got the same exit code with this also.

Comment: @DeepShah : `cmd.exe` or any windows shell command usually return zero on success and non-zero on failure; what you get is as expected.

Comment: @DeepShah : if you want to get text output of the command, see my edit.

Comment: @shrike Ok. So what should i do if i want to open cmd shell with error message on cmd shell on failure of command. because by using /c it is not remain open.

Comment: That's because you're using `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` rather than letting the output go to the current console.

Comment: @HarryJohnston : no, this is not related to `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`

Comment: @DeepShah : if you want the console to remain open on error, see my last edit

Comment: @shrike, it most certainly is!  The problem is that the output is going to a console that disappears when the process exits; if you instead allow it to go the console of the parent process, that won't be an issue.  (But your solution would work too, it depends what the OP is actually trying to achieve.  From the sounds of it your solution might well be preferable.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston : You're right, I though you answered another comment from DeepShah.

Comment: @shrike: Thanks for your help. I checked your edit and now console remain open on error but exit code was 0 for both success and failure.

Comment: @DeepShah : yes, this is because you get exit code of `pause` ; I edited the last snippet in my answer so that you get an exit code of 1 in case of error during `dir` command execution

Comment: @shrike: i tried your updated snippet. i am getting exit code 0 for success and 3221225786 value on failure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DeepShah : That's strange, on my test application, I get an exit code of 1 in case of error... Anyway, if this code answers your question, please accept the answer.